# How to make a splash screen efficiently

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, splash-screen

I am trying to make splash screen for my app so that I can load some data in when I am showing the splash screen .But seems there are many way of making a splash screen.

> 1.Make a new activity with a layout and show that activity for some time.But making another activity with a layout makes the app heavy.
>
> 2.Make a new activity with  no layout and making a splash screen back ground instead as shown [here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/)
>
> 3.Make a fragment with a layout and show them as splash screen as shown [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2066699)

Among all these which is the best way of making a splash screen. I am able to make a splash screen but I want to make it light and easy.

Comment: There is no correct answer. Different people make different implementations to fit their needs and their coding style.

Comment: But the purpose of making a splash screen is same in all and is to load the data in the background

Comment: What data are you loading? Showing your layout with progress could be better UX

Comment: I am loading audio files from the external uri

Comment: Splash is usually not used for loading "data" as such, but rather loading native libraries and starting the app as such.

Comment: User would rather see some progress - number of files loaded, MB downloaded etc...

Comment: so which among these is the best way of making a splash screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.Make a new activity with a layout and show that activity for some time.But making another activity with a layout makes the app heavy.

While making the activity, you use Thread to show the splash screen. Make the Activity thread sleep for few seconds and update background data during sleep is efficient.

Comment: I am doing this but making an activity with a layout makes an app heavy

Comment: @SAVVY you can use activity and call a drawable instead of layout.

Answer (score 1):

*As much as possible* avoid having a splash in your app. As an app user I also have this behavior.

- I really need to use the App immediately because time is precious.
- I have limited patience (probably most people will agree).
- I don't need it at all.

So what if we can't totally avoid having a splash screen? The suggested concept that I gather are these:

- Lazy Loading - Load only those piece of information that is really needed by now. Example : A Movie app: Load only those latest movies rather than those old movies unless the user told you to do so. The idea here is that decided only on which is necessary to load first and load other else later on. With this approached you lessen the time showing your splash screen.
- Caching - If you keep on downloading things from your server chances are it might take too long to load and your splash screen will be visible for longer period of time. With caching you will need to fetch fewer data from the network since you've downloaded some of them already.

Things to consider in creating views.

- Avoid a super deep nested views.
- Avoid a deep nested weights.
- For image loading use some popular library like Picasso, Glide etc.

Comment: so will i use an activity with no layout and show the image via resource file

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: I don't think that we need to avoid having splash screen at least because it's usage described in Material Guideline (https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/launch-screens.html)

Comment: @RuslanBerozov Note I said *As much as possible* but not entirely avoid it. I also give some insights if you can't avoid having no splash screens :)

Comment: @Enzokie there is a compromise option when we can set `<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>` in custom style for start activity