# improve layout performance

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I am freelancing to solve crash of an android app. It happens on startup, and I know it is because the activity_main.xml. It has too many views, too many nesting levels. Apart from that (wich I will try to reduce)

**what are other strategies to improve layout performance in Android?**

The user interface cannot be changed or simplified.
For example:
- for repeated elements (50 - 100), does using 'include' makes it faster?
- the same for defining properties in styles instead of in every item.

Comment: put the layout.

Comment: I am searching for general advice

Comment: Replace repeated items with a `listview` or a `recyclerview`. Also use `PercentRelativeLayout` instead `RelativeLayout` for more layout options.

Comment: How do you know that this is the source of the crash? What is the logcat output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been recently working on  improving performance of app and renderd a fast smooth UI let me share you my experience :

The vision of performance in terms of UI is:

```
Lower the latency of screen draws
Create fast, consistent frame rates to avoid jank/lag.
```

And there are  some thumb rules for layouts .

Minimum view  hierarchy.

minimum background drawbles

minimizing overdraw of window :

minimizing overdraw of Views

using drawble left instead of image and textview aligned horizontally.

using lists/recyclerview very often when repetitive view

and Many more . let me share some links which are really helpful

https://medium.com/@elifbon/android-application-performance-step-1-rendering-ba820653ad3#.pp7hpnv07

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/high-performance-android/9781491913994/ch04.html

https://riggaroo.co.za/optimizing-layouts-in-android-reducing-overdraw/

https://www.hackerearth.com/notes/rendering-performance-in-android-overdraw/

Letme know if it's helpful. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can try following from https://developer.android.com,

[**Optimizing Layout**](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html#Revise)

1. Inspect Your Layout
2. Revise Your Layout
3. Use Lint

AS well as

[**Improving Layout Performance**](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/index.html)

1. Optimizing Layout Hierarchies
2. Re-using Layouts with
3. Loading Views On Demand
4. Re-using Layouts with

Answer (score 1):

I have answered a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39332878/5217712) before and my advice is still applicable in this topic.

**Handling loads:**

*Lazy Loading* - Load only those piece of information that is really needed by now. Example : A Movie app: Load only those latest movies rather than those old movies unless the user told you to do so. The idea here is that decided only on which is necessary to load first and load other else later on. The lesser the load the greater the performance is while without sacrificing a good content.

*Caching* - If you keep on downloading things from your server chances are it might take too long to load and your splash screen will be visible for longer period of time or some of your UI might freeze specially when you do it in the Main thread. With caching you will need to fetch fewer data from the network since you've downloaded some of them already.

**Things to consider in creating views.**

- Avoid a super deep nested views.
- Avoid a deep nested weights.
- For image loading use some popular library like Picasso, Glide etc.

> does using 'include' makes it faster?

A bit, Reusing layouts is particularly powerful as it allows you create reusable complex layouts. For example, a yes/no button panel, or custom progress bar with description text. It also means that any elements of your application that are common across multiple layouts can be extracted, managed separately, then included in each layout. So while you can create individual UI components by writing a custom View, you can do it even more easily by re-using a layout file.

Source : [Official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

*Addendum*

When things are still wrong and the Android framework doesn't provide what you really need; the last approach is to **create your own view** via extending `View` or `ViewGroup`. Creating your own view/layout requires time and much effort but you gain more controls since it is your own view/layout implementation, let say *you have the power to change the world*.